# Local maximum identification within a set % (trigger True on the downside)

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

Looking to identify (flag True) when current values in col1 drop below the most recent local maximum in col1 achieved by a set percent such that there will be multiple such signals as maxima are achieved and current values drop by the set percent (i.e. resets automatically without a set threshold other than the percent). Note that flag True should occur only on downside, not upside.

```
percent = 0.7
df = pd.DataFrame({'col0':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
      ,'col1':[5,4.9,5.5,3.5,3.1,4.5,5.5,1.2,5.8]
      ,'col2':[3.5, 3.43, 3.85, 2.45, 2.17, 3.15, 3.85, 0.84, 4.06]
      ,'col3':[np.nan, 3.43, 3.85, 3.85, 3.85, 3.85, 3.85, 3.85, 4.06]
      })
df['col2'] = df['col1'] * percent
df['col3'] = df['col2'].shift(-1).cummax().shift()
```

Current form of col3 generates cummax but desired result will find local maxima to the downside and col4 to flag True every time col1 breaches col3 to the downside. Here's one example of the resulting col3 and col4:

```
   col0  col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1   5.0  3.50   NaN False
1     2   4.9  3.43  3.43 False
2     3   5.5  3.85  3.85 False
3     4   3.5  2.45  3.85  True
4     5   3.1  2.17  3.85 False
5     6   4.5  3.15  3.85 False
6     7   5.5  3.85  3.85 False
7     8   1.2  0.84  3.85  True
8     9   5.8  2.90  4.06 False
```

[image: illustration]

Comment: Are you just looking for df['col1'] < df['col3']?

Comment: @ScottBoston yes on the first instance after the local max..col1 could remain < col3 as in point 5 in the diagram but point 5 shouldn’t flag True because it is not coming from a local max

Comment: Gotcha... your df['col3'] part in this question isn't correct, I think you meant to use the other with groupby.

Comment: @ScottBoston yes the df['col3'] needs reworking along the lines of your groupby..but just wasn’t sure what form it should take for this local max problem without a specific/constant threshold..

Comment: Not  quite sure o f a good way to determine local maximums.  I'll upvote this question, with the hopes someone else will have a better idea.